# Hibernate Criteria with joins not generating correct SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sap-ase

I'm trying to execute a Criteria query but when I execute the code, the SQL only brings up company_synonym in the from clause, not the other two.

The mappings are:

- Company has 1-to-Many CompanySynonyms
- Company has 1-to-Many CompanyProductRoles

I want the query to return CompanySynonym objects, so I tried this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CompanySynonym.class, "cs")
    .createAlias("cs." + CompanySynonym.COMPANY, "cmp")
    .createAlias("cmp." + Company.COMPANY_PRODUCT_ROLE, "cpr")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("cs." + CompanySynonym.TYPE, "1234"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("cpr." + CompanyProductRole.PRODUCT_ID, Integer.valueOf(productId)))
    .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("cpr." + CompanySynonym.Company_ID))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("cpr." + CompanyProductRole.ROLE_CODE, "AB"));
```

And it generates this SQL:

```
select this_.company_syn_id_i as company1_0_0_, this_.company_id_i as company5_0_0_, this_.cmp_syn_end_d as cmp2_0_0_, this_.cmp_syn_type_cd_c as cmp3_0_0_, this_.cmp_syn_c as cmp4_0_0_ 
from product.dbo.company_synonym this_ 
where this_.cmp_syn_type_cd_c=? 
and cpr1_.product_id_i=? 
and cpr1_.company_id_i is not null 
and cpr1_.role_cd_c=c
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: From the info you provide, my best guess is that you are only providing a unidirectional association,  i.e. that you need to specify a "inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(...)}" in your @JoinTable association for the Company entity. Search for "bidierctional joins" or "inverse joins" for Hibernate.

Comment: I actually map with @JoinColumn on both sides, would this provide this side effect?